# module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'plot_roc_curve'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am trying to plot ROC curve for stratifiedKfold validation. Heres the code-

```py
from sklearn import metrics

# Run classifier with crossvalidation and plot ROC curves
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
    logisticRegr.fit(X[train], y[train])
    viz = metrics.plot_roc_curve(logisticRegr, X[test], y[test],
                         name='ROC fold {}'.format(i),
                         alpha=0.3, lw=1, ax=ax)
    interp_tpr = np.interp(mean_fpr, viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
    interp_tpr[0] = 0.0
    tprs.append(interp_tpr)
    aucs.append(viz.roc_auc)

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
        label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
ax.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
        label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
        lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
ax.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

ax.set(xlim=[-0.05, 1.05], ylim=[-0.05, 1.05],
       title="Receiver operating characteristic example")
ax.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

I am getting this error-

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'plot_roc_curve'
```

The version is 0.21.3.

Comment: How are you importing `sklearn.metrics`?

Comment: @HansMusgrave Added in the question

Comment: Could you pls specify the version of sklearn.

Comment: @DanyloBaibak I added it,

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade `sklearn` to version 0.22 or later.
As per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v0.22.html#version-0-22-0), `plot_roc_curve` has been added from version 0.22

> Major Feature metrics.plot_roc_curve has been added to plot roc
> curves. This function introduces the visualization API described in
> the User Guide. #14357 by Thomas Fan.